# What is a good PHP analytics script?

Tags: php, content-management-system, google-analytics

I've created a completely custom website with a custom CMS.  I would like to be able to use Google Analytics to get information such as visitor count, popular pages, visitor location(?), etc.  I'm not into the analytics part of websites yet, so I've been looking for some easy ways to implement GA into the CMS.  I'd love for the analytics dashboar to look similar to Blogger's analytics dashboard.

Does anyone have experience with a script that will get information from GA, and display it in a nice format?

Thanks!

By the way, I am very new to GA, so sorry if some of this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/about/) is a good option. It is open source and exposes a web API, so you can probably customize it to your needs.

Comment: It's not a Google Analytics client though, it's a Google Analytics competitor.

Comment: I have heard of Piwik, and wasn't sure about it.  Just downloaded it and I'm seeing how it works.  I don't care whether it's with GA or not, as long as it works.  :)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about Piwik!  I downloaded it before, but it didn't work at the time.  Now it works, and I think I will probably end up using it.